# spring boot soap example don't printout response

Tags: java, spring, soap, spring-boot

`spring boot` soap example don't printout response.

Add this line please

```
@Bean
CommandLineRunner lookup(WeatherClient weatherClient) {
        return args -> {
            String zipCode = "94304";

            if (args.length > 0) {
                zipCode = args[0];
            }
            GetCityForecastByZIPResponse response = weatherClient.getCityForecastByZip(zipCode);
            ///  ADD THIS LINE PLEASEEEEEE            
            weatherClient.printResponse(response);
        };
}
```